# Travis-ci tests an option I excluded. I'm missing something the testing matrix setup,

Tags: travis-ci

for some reason Travis-CI run all the matrix including all 3.3 (and not only vs django 1.6)
the `.travis.yml` code:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.3"
env:
  - DJANGO=Django==1.5.1
  - DJANGO=Django==1.4.3
  - DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/
matrix:
  # since isn't a Django release
  allow failures:
  - env: DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/
  # since most django versions won't work with 3.3. excluded won't run on the matrix
  exclude:
  - python: "3.3"
  #the only version of django that's supposed to support 3.3
  include:
  - python: "3.3"
    env: DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/

install:
  - pip install -q $DJANGO --use-mirrors
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --use-mirrors
  - pip install -q django-setuptest --use-mirrors
script:
  - python setup.py test
```

what am I missing? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
env:
  - DJANGO=Django==1.5.1
  - DJANGO=Django==1.4.3
  - DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/
matrix:
  # since isn't a Django release
  allow_failures:
  - env: DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/
  #the only version of django that's supposed to support 3.3
  include:
  - python: "3.3"
    env: DJANGO=https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6b1/tarball/

install:
  - pip install -q $DJANGO --use-mirrors
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --use-mirrors
  - pip install -q django-setuptest --use-mirrors
script:
  - python setup.py test
```

Basically, for every `matrix.exclude`, you have to specify the *entire* config for a job. So to remove one of the 3.3 jobs you would do this:

```
matrix:
  exclude:
    - python: "3.3"
      env: DJANGO=Django==1.5.1
```

You would then have to add another one for 1.4.3 as well. Just removing `"3.3"` from `python` is easier, since it'll be added with the `matrix.include` anyways.

Comment: thanks @henrikhodne, I think include and exclude should be explained better in the docs.. Do you think I should make a pull request for this?

Comment: We'd love pull requests for documentation suggestions. We'd like to improve them ourselves as well, but it's great to hear suggestions for how people who don't know the code in and out (ie. the target audience for the documentation) explains something. Our documentation repository is at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci.github.com.